# Similate a vessel being filled with a liquid

Tags: animation

I would appreciate some help with the following:

I am trying to animate filling a non-uniform shaped mesh with a liquid. I do not want to use a fluid modifier. The end result I need is just a graphical simulation for a web page.

[image]

As you can see the vessel is an 'odd shape'

Any pointers towards a solution would be appreciated.

Thanks

Richard C

Comment: Would this help? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143307/how-to-fake-fluid-in-a-jar-while-moving-jar-around

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to raise the liqud level, you can have the inner shape with a volumetric material sat up as water and then make a cube and add wave modifier to it. Then add a boolean modifier to ineract with the inner shape of the Vessel. Then animate the cube to rise up in Z direction. (The inner shape of the vessel must be seperated object from the vessel) Also I suggest to retopology the mesh, it seems that there are some n-gons in your mesh that are causing some shadowing problems or could be wrong sided normals...

Comment: Thanks Edge3D - the link is very useful information and solution for a different issue I will face later in the project.

Mohammadreza - many thanks - your suggested workflow is a perfect solution for this problem

Comment: No problem! @Richard